# XML validation with XSD fails while online validators pass

Tags: c#, xml, mono, xsd-validation

I have a simple XML file that I want to validate against an XSD. However, whenever I run my validation code, I get a validation exception saying the "multitest" node is undefined (unlocalized error message: "The multitest element is not declared."). The strange thing is that I tried to validate the XML against the XSD on a couple of online validation sites (http://www.xmlvalidation.com, http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html), and they say the XML is perfectly valid.

This is the code I use to validate (C# with the Mono library)

```
// Resources.tests contains the XSD file in string format, xmlFileName points to the XML file location
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader (Resources.tests)) {
    XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create (sr);
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings ();
    settings.Schemas.Add (null, r);
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream (xmlFileName, FileMode.Open)) {
        var reader = XmlReader.Create (fs, settings);
        while (reader.Read ()) {
            // Nothing in here, just need to read out the entire file in a loop.
        }
    }
}
```

This is the XML file I try to validate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<multitest>
    <testfile>
        <location>blah.xml</location>
    </testfile>
</multitest>
```

The XSD is quite simple as well:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="multitest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="testfile" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="location"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

What am I missing?

Addition:

Strangely, the same code works perfectly on the XML and XSD given below:

XSD:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="tests">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="test" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="sample"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="cmd"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="result"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tests>
  <test>
    <sample>blahblah.txt</sample>
    <cmd>samplecmd</cmd>
    <result>blahblahblah_result.txt</result>
  </test>
</tests>
```

Comment: Could it be that the XML that is failing contains a Byte Order Marker that is causing it to fail? Usually that error manifests itself by saying "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, Column 1" or something of that ilk, however. It could be worth a shot to check for that anyway.

Comment: @noMad17 Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't seem to be the issue. Using NP++, both setting/converting to UTF8 with/without BOM gives errors in both cases. The exact error (unlocalized) is: "The multitest element is not declared."

Comment: Do you have multiple culture specific resource files? Tried hardcoding the XSD into a string and trying?

Comment: @potatopeelings Hardcoding into a string doesn't work either. There are no specific resource files, just a single one.

Comment: Probably not useful, but it works fine in .NET - https://dotnetfiddle.net/CjPCU3

Comment: And, stating the bleeding obvious, are you sure you're validating against the correct schema?  Your code has `new StringReader(Resources.tests)` which looks like the name of your second schema.  You'd get this error if you used the second one.

Comment: *sinks ashamedly away in the ground*

Wrong schema indeed. Went up so much into searching for other issues that I totally overlooked that.

Comment: @CharlesMager should post the comment as an answer so he can get the 50 bounty points...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would vote this is closed as it's essentially a typo rather than an actual problem.

For completeness, I'll point out that you're validating against the wrong schema.  Your first line that reads your schema string is this:

```
using (StringReader sr = new StringReader (Resources.tests))
```

And `Resources.tests` sounds like it refers to the second schema in your question (and you have confirmed this).  Simply change this to the correct schema and it should resolve your issue.